# How do i create a coin for my coin flip simulator?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I created my Coin class for my Coin toss simulator but I have a few questions, what am I missing to make it flip 20 times (or is that something I write in the program?) and also, how do I create a "Coin" in my program?
Here's the class so far...

```
   import java.util.Random;
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Coin
   {
   private String sideUp;
   private int headCount;
   private int tailCount;

   private Random rand = new Random();

   public void toss()
   {
      sideUp = "";
      headCount = 0;
      tailCount = 0;
      Random rand = new Random();


      //Get random value 0 or 1
      int value = rand.nextInt(2);
      if(value == 0 )
      {
         this.sideUp = "heads";
         headCount++;
      }
      else
      {
         this.sideUp = "tails";
         tailCount++;
      }

   }
   public String getSideUp(String sideUp)
   {
      this.sideUp = "";
      headCount = 0;
      tailCount = 0;
      return sideUp;
   }
   public int getHeadCount(int headCount)
   {
      this.sideUp = "";
      this.headCount = 0;
      tailCount = 0;
      return headCount;
   }
   public int getTailCount(int tailCount)
   {
      this.sideUp = "";
      this.headCount = 0;
      this.tailCount = 0;
      return tailCount;
   }
}
```

Comment: Just a side comment: rather than refer to the coin face as a String, this is a good example where you could use an Enum for better type safety, as you have a finite number of states, either CoinFace.Heads or CoinFace.Tails. sideUp will then be of type CoinFace instead of String

Comment: I see what you mean, but the teacher gave us a UML diagram with the variables we were supposed to use for this program :/

Comment: That's a shame, but if you need to follow the provided design for the sake of the class, then you should. However, as an additional learning point, it would be valuable to note that the String type is not exactly a great fit for representing two finite states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `main()` method, which is necessary to run your code as an application.  Try the following:

```
public class Coin {
    // keep your original code...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Coin theCoin = new Coin();
        for (int i=0; i < 20; ++i) {
            theCoin.toss();
        }

        System.out.println("Coin was heads " + theCoin.getHeadCount() + " times.");
        System.out.println("Coin was tails " + theCoin.getTailCount() + " times.");

    }
}
```

Comment: Ty tim, this code I have was just the class. I was so tired (I finished my other 2 assignments already) I forgot to show how far I had gotten with my actual program at the time.